# Oracle function returning all columns from tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkLiveSoccerOdd (p_FIXID    VARCHAR2,
                                               p_TYPE     VARCHAR2,
                                               p_RES      VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   odd   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT O.Odd
     INTO odd
     FROM LIVE M, ODDS O
    WHERE     M.FIXID = O.FIXID(+)
          AND M.FIXID = p_FIXID
          AND O.TYPE = p_TYPE
          AND O.RES = p_RES;

   RETURN odd;
END;
```

Now i need to get more columns in query, for example:

```
Select  M.*,  O.*
```

I tried with cursor but I don't get results. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Return a `sys_refcursor` inplace of just returning a number.

Comment: You say "you want more columns in query" - do you mean exactly that?  You want more values returned by the SQL statement but you still only need to return a single value as the result of the function?

Comment: I want all columns in these two tables to be returned.

Comment: @ChristianPalmer Yes, I would like to get all values returned from tables, when I pass these parameters....  With this select i get only O.Odd.

Comment: Use ANSI `JOIN` syntax for `LEFT JOIN`s. Get rid of the  confusing `(+)` notation

Comment: @KaushikNayak wise words, especially since the presence of the `and o.type = p_type and o.res = p_res` predicates make it an inner join anyway! (To the OP: to make the query do a left outer join, you should add the `(+)`s to all references to the odds tables, e.g. `and o.type (+) = p_type and o.res (+) = p_res`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkLiveSoccerOdd (p_FIXID    VARCHAR2,
                                               p_TYPE     VARCHAR2,
                                               p_RES      VARCHAR2)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   COL   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN COL FOR
   SELECT M.*,O.*    
     FROM LIVE M, ODDS O
    WHERE     M.FIXID = O.FIXID(+)
          AND M.FIXID = p_FIXID
          AND O.TYPE = p_TYPE
          AND O.RES = p_RES;

   RETURN COL;
END;
```

Comment: That helps a bit but i get it all in one column, can i get all columns separated ?

Comment: If you execute it in  a select statement you get it in a single column but if you execute in a anonymous block, you can display it separatly.