# Oracle function with select all from tables

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.* FROM LABALES L , MATCHES M 
WHERE M.LIST LIKE '%ENG' 
ORDER BY L.ID
```

I need to create function with this select, I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSoccerLists
RETURN varchar2  IS 
list varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
   SELECT DISTINCT L.* FROM LABALES L , MATCHES M 
   WHERE M.LIST LIKE '%ENG' 
   ORDER BY L.ID
   return list;
END;
```

How will I create function that returns all from table L.

Thanks

Comment: No join conditions? That query doesn't make much sense...

Comment: What error it is giving??

Comment: @jarlh When i run select i get results so select is good. But i want it in function..

Comment: @NishantGupta sql statment ignored, end of line of qouted identifer ,missing double qoute

Comment: sorry,but the follwong link is not from SO but will definetly help you to solve your problem-
https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2017/01/22/oracle-return-select-statement-results-like-sql-server-sps-using-pipelined-functions/

Comment: Why do you want a function in the first place? If you just want to store the query for reuse, then make it a view. And as has been mentioned: The query makes no sense. You duplicate LABALES records by the number of '%ENG' MATCHES and then you dismiss all duplicates again with `DISTINCT`. You'll probably get the same result with a mere `select * from labales`.

Comment: I been told to make function or procedure instead of query, probably not to run select all the time when someone needs this results.
This is the select i want in function {SELECT DISTINCT L.* FROM SOCCER_PREMATCH_LISTS L , SOCCER_PREMATCH_MATCHES M 
WHERE M.LIST LIKE '%' || (L.SUB_LIST) || '%' AND (TO_TIMESTAMP((M.M_DATE || ' ' || M.M_TIME), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') 
> (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET' FROM DUAL))
ORDER BY L.ID; }

Answer (score 1):

You may use implicit result using `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`(Oracle12c and above) in a procedure using a cursor to your query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getSoccerLists 
AS
x SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN x FOR SELECT DISTINCT L.* FROM LABALES L 
   JOIN  MATCHES M  ON ( 1=1 ) -- join condition
       WHERE M.LIST LIKE '%ENG' 
       ORDER BY L.ID; 
   DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(x);
END;
/
```

then simply call the procedure

```
EXEC getSoccerLists;
```

For lower versions(Oracle 11g) , you may use a print command to display the cursor's o/p passing ref cursor as out parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getSoccerLists (x OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN x FOR SELECT DISTINCT L.* FROM LABALES L 
   JOIN  MATCHES M  ON ( 1=1 ) -- join condition
       WHERE M.LIST LIKE '%ENG' 
       ORDER BY L.ID; 
END;
/
```

Then, in SQL* Plus or running as script in SQL developer and Toad, you may get the results using this.

```
VARIABLE r REFCURSOR;
EXEC  getSoccerLists (:r);

PRINT r;
```

Another option is to use TABLE function by defining a collection of the record type of the result within a package.

Refer [Create an Oracle function that returns a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829880/create-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-table)

Comment: `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` will work only in Oracle 12c.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak  when i do like you wrote it i get error pls 00302 compomnent Return_result must be declared

Comment: @civesuas_sine : You should be using 11g ?  Refer my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this questions is a repetition of the your previously asked question, where you wanted to get all the columns of tables but into separate column. I already answered in stating this you cannot do if you call your function via a `SELECT` statement. If you call your function in a Anoymous block you can display it in separate columns.

Here [Oracle function returning all columns from tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650951/oracle-function-returning-all-columns-from-tables/49651072#49651072)

Alternatively, you can get the results separated by a comma(`,`) or pipe (`|`) as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION getSoccerLists
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    list VARCHAR2(2000);
  BEGIN
    SELECT col1
      ||','
      ||col2
      ||','
      ||col2
    INTO LIST
    FROM SOCCER_PREMATCH_LISTS L ,
      SOCCER_PREMATCH_MATCHES M
    WHERE M.LIST LIKE '%' || (L.SUB_LIST)  || '%'
    AND (TO_TIMESTAMP((M.M_DATE      || ' '      || M.M_TIME), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') >
      (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET' FROM DUAL
      ))
    ORDER BY L.ID");
  Return list;
  End;
```

Note here if the column size increased 2000 chars then again you will lose the data.

Edit:

From your comments

> I want it to return a table set of results.

You then need to create a table of `varchar` and then return it from the function. See below:

```
CREATE TYPE var IS  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION getSoccerLists
  RETURN var
IS
  --Initialization
  list VAR :=var();
BEGIN
  SELECT NSO ||',' ||NAME BULK COLLECT INTO LIST FROM TEST;
  RETURN list;
END;
```

Execution:

```
select * from table(getSoccerLists);
```

Note: Here in the function i have used a table called test and its column. You replace your table with its columnname.

**Edit 2:**

```
--Create a object with columns same as your select statement
CREATE   TYPE v_var IS  OBJECT
(
col1 NUMBER,
col2 VARCHAR2(10)
)
/
--Create a table of your object
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE var IS TABLE OF v_var;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSoccerLists
  RETURN var
IS
  --Initialization
  list VAR :=var();
BEGIN
   --You above object should have same columns with same data type as you are selecting here 
  SELECT v_var( NSO ,NAME) BULK COLLECT INTO LIST FROM TEST;
  RETURN list;
END;
```

Execution:

```
select * from table(getSoccerLists);
```

Comment: @civesuas_sine. You need to put your actual columns. I am not giving ready made code for you. It's just a demo to help out your issue. Just replace all the columns of your table separate it via a `,` or `|`.

Comment: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: @civesuas_sine it means your query returns multiple rows on your filter clause. If this is the case then again either you need to make sure your query return a single row or you need to return a table of your resultset using either a `sys_refcursor` or by decalring a `object`

Comment: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object , when I try to run statement

Comment: @civesuas_sine Not sure what and how you are executing. I showed you a working demo. Also as mentioned earlier, you cannot do as you showed in the pic. At max you can separate the results using `,` or `|` and display result in a single column since you are returning a table of varchar. Or you need to create a object of your table type and then use it. See edit2

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer on how to build a function for this, as I'd recommend to make this a view instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_soccer_list AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM soccer_prematch_lists l
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM soccer_prematch_matches m 
    WHERE m.list LIKE '%' || (l.sub_list) || '%' 
      AND TO_TIMESTAMP((m.m_date || ' ' || m.m_time), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') > 
            (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET' FROM DUAL)
  );
```

Then call it in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM view_soccer_list ORDER BY id;
```

(It makes no sense to put an `ORDER BY` clause in a view, because you access the view like a table, and table data is considered unordered, so you could not rely on that order. The same is true for a pipelined function youd access with `FROM TABLE (getSoccerLists)`. Always put the `ORDER BY` clause in your final queries instead.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettnerDont need view, can you just create function using this select ?

Comment: Well, I just thought it makes no sense to have a function do the same thing. The only difference to a view is that it's slower. If you want to write a function anyway, you may want to look up pipelined functions: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions